# How to make first row header with Apache Spark in SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

Can someone show me how to make the first row header=True with Apache Spark on Databricks using magic SQL.

The code that I'm using is

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW enrraces.race_circuits_df
AS SELECT *
FROM csv.`/FileStore/tables/results.csv`
```

I just want to make the first row the header.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
%sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW enrraces.race_circuits_df
USING CSV
OPTIONS (path "/FileStore/tables/results.csv", header "true");

SELECT *
FROM enrraces.race_circuits_df
```

OR

```
%sql USE enrraces;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW race_circuits_df
USING CSV
OPTIONS (path "/FileStore/tables/results.csv", header "true");

SELECT * FROM race_circuits_df
```

Comment: Hi Assaf, I'm getting the following error:
== SQL ==
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW enrraces.race_circuits_df
USING CSV
^^^
OPTIONS (path "/FileStore/tables/results.csv", header "true")
AS SELECT *
FROM csv.`/FileStore/tables/results.csv`

Comment: Actually, the full error is:
```mismatched input 'USING' expecting {'(', 'AS', 'COMMENT', 'PARTITIONED', 'TBLPROPERTIES'}(line 2, pos 0)

== SQL ==
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW enrraces.race_circuits_df
USING CSV
^^^
OPTIONS (path "/FileStore/tables/results.csv", header "true")
AS SELECT *
FROM csv.`/FileStore/tables/results.csv```

Comment: @Patterson can you try either of the solutions I just added? edited my answer.

Comment: Hi, this worked for me

```%sql
create table if not exists enrraces.race_circuits_df using csv 
options ('header' = 'true') 
location "/FileStore/tables/results.csv"```

Comment: great! @Patterson